# c# Prevent try icon MouseDoubleClick event multiple times

Tags: c#

How can i prevent try icon MouseDoubleClick event while running a method? Because when i double click try icon while running a method, mouse click events queuing and than executing the method again when it ends. Try icon does not have disable property. So i tried putting following event handlers at the beginning and end of  the method but did not work.

```
//Begining;
tryicon.MouseDoubleClick -= new MouseEventHandler(tryicon_MouseDoubleClick);

//End;
tryicon.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler(tryicon_MouseDoubleClick);
```

And i also tried;

```
private bool IsExecuted = false;

//Method Beginnig
IsExecuted = true;
//Method End
IsExecuted = false;

//MouseDoubleClickEvent
if(IsExecuted == false)
{
 Method();
}
else
{
MessageBox("Already Running")
}
```

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` Event and check following condition in the event block

```
if(e.ClickCount > 1 )
{
  e.Handle = true;
  return;
}
```